# Using TFS 2012 to build Visual COBOL 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cobol.net

I'm trying to use TFS 2012 to build a Visual COBOL 2012 solution.

I have configured TFS 2012 to use the 32-bit version of MSBuild but I'm still having problems and get the errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Micro Focus\Visual
>   COBOL\v1.0\MicroFocus.COBOL.targets(262,9): error : MSBMF002 - An
>   internal error occurred. Exception text follows:
>   [D:\Builds\1\Cobol.NET\COBOLConsoleApplication\Sources\COBOLConsoleApplication\COBOLConsoleApplication\COBOLConsoleApplication.cblproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Micro Focus\Visual
>   COBOL\v1.0\MicroFocus.COBOL.targets(262,9): error : Value cannot be
>   null.
>   [D:\Builds\1\Cobol.NET\COBOLConsoleApplication\Sources\COBOLConsoleApplication\COBOLConsoleApplication\COBOLConsoleApplication.cblproj]
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Micro Focus\Visual
>   COBOL\v1.0\MicroFocus.COBOL.targets(262,9): error : Parameter name:
>   path1
>   [D:\Builds\1\Cobol.NET\COBOLConsoleApplication\Sources\COBOLConsoleApplication\COBOLConsoleApplication\COBOLConsoleApplication.cblproj]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Given this is giving you an "internal error"... I would recommend you contact Micro Focus or place this information on the community.microfocus.com visual cobol forum.